# onItemClick is conflict with onItemClickListener of SwipeListViewCallback

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-listview, swipe

i have used the following :

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeListViewCallback {

private ListView category_linear;
//code...
category_linear.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                Intent ii = new Intent(context, otherscreen.class);
                startActivity(ii);

            }
        });
```

and i have also the method of SwipeListViewCallback:

```
@Override
public void onItemClickListener(ListAdapter adapter, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

when i click once on listview item then it is not open other activity.

When click twice then and then it is working.

I want to open other activity on listview item on one click

Comment: Why you are using both Listener ? just use `category_linear.setOnItemClickListener(this);` and move start next activity related code in `onItemClickListener` method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK When i removed that listener of swipelistviewcallback then it shows error `Add unimplemented methods`

Comment: Please reread my comment i'm saying replace  anonymous listener which you are passing in `setOnItemClickListener` which `this`

Comment: when i write this `-category_linear.setOnItemClickListener(this);` then it show the error  `The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (CategoryFragment)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
I have removed the `onItemClickListener` from SwipeListView class.
```

and also removed the method of swipe listview.

```
 @Override
public void onItemClickListener(ListAdapter adapter, int position) {
    }
```

So when i click on the item from list view then it is called the list view on click listener.